# How to push object data in array by index?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, angular12

I have below code.

```
test = [];

ngOnInit() {

this.test.push({ "start": 0.1 });
this.test.push({ "start": 0.2, "end": 0.5 });

this.test.forEach((res, index) => {
  console.log(index + "=" + res.start)
})

console.log(this.test);
}
```

I want to push data at `0` index with "end" : 0.15.

I tried with `splice` but didn't worked.

So output will be

```
[{
        "start": 0.1,
        "end": 0.15
    },
    {
        "start": 0.2,
        "end": 0.5
    }
]
```

Comment: are you perhaps looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Comment: Hi @MikkelChristensen Not much useful

Comment: If only want to add a new property or change: `this.test[0].end= 0.15`, if you want to replace `this.test[0]={start:this.test[0].start,end: 0.15}`, if you want to add to the beginning `this.test.unshift({start:0,end: 0.15})`. Really I feel that the link Mikkel indicate you is a good reference.

Comment: Hi @Eliseo. This works what I am looking for `this.test[0].end= 0.15`. Can put in answer to can accept it. Thank you again :)